# Как собрать приложение для XP в Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10, cmake, windows-xp

Как собрать приложение на Win10, которое будет работать в WinXP? Скачал `Windows XP support extension`, указал для проекта свойство `Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)`, однако всё равно на WinXP при попытке запуска приложения пишется "Приложение не является Win32 приложением". С чем это может быть связано? Используется только стандартный C++, никаких библиотек или расширений, которые могли появиться позже WinXP нет. Можеть быть нужен SDK другой версии? Ещё такой момент: решение генерируется с помощью CMake с генератором `Visual Studio 15 2017`, а не вручную. Пробовал там указать явно архитектуру `-A Win32` (вдруг проблема с 32/64 битностью) - то же самое.

Comment: Какая битность системы? Какая *фактическая* битность у собранного бинарика?

Comment: @VTT собираю на Win10 x64, а надо запустить на WinXP x32

Comment: @VTT но в конфиге выбрал Release-Win32, так что должно быть x32 в итоге по идее

Comment: Так а какая битность получилась на самом деле?

Comment: По выяснению разрядности можете [тут подсмотреть ответ](https://superuser.com/a/889267/362161).

Comment: Если вы выбрали Win32 в на тулбаре VS, из этого совсем не следует, что данный проект будет так собираться. Там зависимость немного сложнее. Сделайте Rebuild и посмотрите что пишется в окошке Output, там в начале лога указывается конфигурация проекта.

Comment: А что, MSVC Redistributable 2017 проблем не вызвал? Встал на XP?

Comment: @MasterAler, а зачем он там? Ясно же, что надо использовать статическую линковку.

Answer (score 1):

Заработало. Проблема оказалась достаточно банальной, но не очевидной для меня. Надо указывать `Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)` не только для `ALL_BUILD` проекта, но и для всех проектов, которые сгенерировал `CMake`. Я думал, что если указать в `ALL_BUILD`, то значит, все собираемые проекты получат это свойство, но оказалось, что нет. Возможно, можно указать это для всего решения, а не указывать для каждого проекта, но это уже мелочи.

Comment: В VS в свойствах проекта есть опция, `support Windows XP (v141_xp)`